# How do I get a fill to overlap a line using matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to plot a chart where the fill is semi-transparent and colors the line plots that it overlaps. In this example, I want the x2 line to be halfway between black and red. In other words, if I set alpha to 1, the x2 line shouldn't be visible at all since it would be completely covered by the fill.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = []
x2 = []
y  = []

for i in range(0, 99):
    x1.append(i)
    x2.append(i/2)
    y.append(i)

plt.plot(x1, 'black', x2, 'black')
plt.fill_between(x1, 0, y, color='red', alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't think the question is clear enough. Maybe there is an assumtion  about transparency involved, which is not actually valid, so you may clearly describe what you see and what you expect instead. ("Halfway between black and red" is not clear).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `fill_between()` is automatically drawing underneath the plotted lines. If I understood your question, you want the fill to be above the line. In that case, you need to provide a higher `zorder` value:

```
plt.fill_between(x1, 0, y, color='red', alpha=0.5, zorder=100)
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you!